# Android program flow control in presence of startActivityForResult call

Tags: android, android-activity, event-handling

The program in question, when run on Android, controls slave Bluetooth (BT) devices. It has few buttons which enable different functions of the peer devices.

Bluetooth is not enabled by default on the Android device, and the connection is established for short periods after button(s) click.

So, the flow after each button click is:

1. ensure BT enabled (`startActivityForResult()` with BT enable intent if not)
2. connect to the remote device
3. enable some function of the remote device
4. disconnect from the device

My issue is that if BT is not enabled, then a call to `startActivityForResult()` in #1 "breaks" the program flow. Later, when `onActivityResult()` is called, I want to resume the flow from the point where it was "breaked".

For that purpose I defined additional member field and  few constants and used them in `onActivityResult()`:

```
private int mRerunMethodIndex = 0;
private static final int RERUN_METHOD1 = 1;
private static final inr RERUN_METHOD2 = 2;
...
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                int rerunMethodIndex = mRerunMethodIndex;
                mRerunMethodIndex = 0;
                switch (rerunMethodIndex ) {
                    case (RERUN_METHOD1):
                        method1();
                        break;
                    case (RERUN_METHOD2):
                        method2();
                        break;
                    // ... the same for other cases
                }
            }
            break;    
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Now, one more complication: `onActivityResult()` will be called before activity's `onResume()`. This will matter if any of the `methodX()` need to alter views hierarchy. In my case these methods replace some Fragments, and if this operation is executed from `onActivityResult()` then exception is thrown.

In order to resolve this additional issue, the ugly `switch` from `onActivityResult()` migrates to `onPostResume()`.

The approach described above works, but it is one of the ugliest pieces of code I've ever written: `methodX()` "registers" itself for "rerun" by assigning `RERUN_METHOD_X` constant to `mRerunMethodIndex`, `onActivityResults()` sets some "rerun flag" after BT is enabled, `onPostResume()` checks the flag, clears this flag, clears `mRerunMethodIndex` and reruns the appropriate `methodX()`.

Is there a more elegant approach (preferably confined to 1 or 2 methods)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use runnable to organize your workflow without using step constants. For example:

```
public void Runnable mMethod1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // your code for method 1
    }
}

public void Runnable mMethod2 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // your code for method 2
    }
}

public void Runnable mMethod3 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // your code for method 3
    }
}

private void startMethod(Runnable method) {
    mCurrentMethod = method;
    method.run();
}

...

public vond onPostResume() {
    if (mCurrentMethod != null) {
        mCurrentMethod.run();
        mCurrentMethod = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like some variation of the Command design pattern. I'm not entirely sure that this approach will simplify the code, but it is indeed an interesting one. I'll try to see how it works next time I got into this situation.